# Unsubscribe from all subscribers in multiple member ID's

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email-studio

I am building a custom unsubscription pgae. The code works fine for that particular BU. The subscriber is getting unsubscribed successfully.But, not from the other member ID's that i am embedding in the link.

I have used the unsubscribe code - To unsubscribe a subscriber from ALL Subscribers and her's the link in which i am passing the values

`%%=RedirectTo(URLencode(Concat('https://{Cloud page URL}?SubscriberKey=',AttributeValue('_subscriberkey'),'&mid=',Concat(AttributeValue('memberid'),','{Memberid_2}),'&JobID=',AttributeValue('jobid'),'&BatchID=',AttributeValue('_JobSubscriberBatchID'),'&Reason=',Concat('one click unsubscribe from email footer') ,'&Locale=',AttributeValue('Locale'),'&ver=',GUID())))=%%`

The functionality is working fine from which the email is being sent, but is not getting updated in the BU.

Answer (score 1):

This all comes down to the configuration of your Business Unit settings. When configuring a BU, you can decide whether unsubscribes there should apply across all your BUs in the account. This is done in Setup on per BU basis:

[image]

If you want to keep your unsubscribe settings local (leaving it set to: *Subscribers will be unsubscribed from this business unit only*), you can put your CloudPage in your ENT BU, and log UnSubEvent multiple times (once per the BU in which you want to unsubscribe your contact) see the sample code shown e.g. in the documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/unsubscribing_and_logging_an_unsubevent_with_a_logunsubevent_execute_call.html), or you can use the exact code provided by Gortonington on his [blog here](https://gortonington.com/logunsubevent-and-how-to-do-it-in-wsproxy/), where he uses WSProxy to impersonate specific MID.